# How to set blob limit while creating column in oracle

Tags: oracle, blob

How to set blob limit while creating column in oracle?
I am getting error with

```
Foo (1k)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefblob.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've posted a link to the documentation for Java DB.  That's a completely different database engine that happens to be owned by Oracle Corp.

Within the Oracle database, you do not and can not specify a restriction on the length of a `blob`.  You just declare a `blob`.  Either

```
create table foo(
  blob_column blob
);
```

or

```
declare
  l_blob blob;
begin
  null;
end;
```